# How to determine programmatically whether the app is running as a bundle build from play market

Tags: android

Is it possible to determine programmatically if the app is running as play market instant?

Comment: is your app project using android studio, react-native or else? let everyone know so anyone can help you

Comment: it's android studio, but does it matter?

Comment: yes just make it more clear, if you don't want to get a react-native's javascript answer

Comment: I mean if you know why not :) maybe some one else is going to search it for react-native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it using [PackageManagerCompat#isInstantApp()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/instantapps/PackageManagerCompat.html#isInstantApp()).

Or if your app is API 26+, you can use [PackageManager#isInstantApp()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#isInstantApp()).

Comment: thank you and where can I get PackageManagerCompat? It seems like it's not available. I could find PackageManager but it shows error since my minsdk is 24

Comment: It's from the `com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps` library